# Conditional UNIQUE / FK constraints

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to design a database model for the following scenario:

a person can have a bunch of "attributes" describing him or her, each with a number of predefined "values" to choose from. An example of attribute could be `'eyes'` with the possible values of `'hazel'`, `'blue'` and `'green'`. Or `'hair length'` with `'very long'`, `'long'`, `'medium'`, `'short'`, `'very short'`, `'none'` (yes, I know real life has more variety than this but let's keep it simple),

I came up with the following model:

[image]

UNIQUE constraint on `person_id, attribute_id` pair in `person_has_attribute_value` table makes sure there is no more than exactly one value for a given attribute per person. I also want to be able to add / remove / modify the attributes as well as their possible values without messing up data integrity, so all relationships have `CASCADE` on update and delete.

This should work fairly well, but:

**1.** Let's say for some attributes I want to be able to assign multiple values to a person. Is there a way to enforce uniqueness of `person_id, attribute_id` only for some values of `attribute_id` (preferably based on an additional `multiple BOOLEAN` column in the `attribute` table) or do I need a completely different set of tables for such cases?

**2.** Let's say some attributes don't have predefined values and can take arbitrary numerical values instead (e.g.: height or weight). Is there a way to somehow incorporate those in the existing structure while keeping the constraints on those attributes that *do* have predefined values, or do I need yet another set of tables for such cases?

Comment: What you want to do is similar to implementing a small fragment of the UML metamodel (including objects and their attribute-value slots) in the form of a relational DB schema. I think the simplest approach is to represent attribute values as strings, which may be serialized JSON arrays in the case of multi-valued attributes. I recommend first making a UML class model and then turn it into a DB model. [I'm not sure if I'll find the time to do this for you.]

Answer (score 0):

To start with: I like your data model so far.

**As to point 2**: You can use the same data model, if you want so. If for an attribute 'height [cm]' you need the value 182, you can create a record in **attribute_value** with that value and use this. However, as you want to use another input method (typing in a value instead of choosing a value from a list), you need a flag in **attribute** to tell you whether an attribute is a fixed list attribute or a free variable attribute.

**As to point 1**: This is more difficult, because this goes against your constraint. On first glance you have two options here:

1. Drop that constraint. Well, so you *could* suddenly have a person with two different eyes (and wow, you could even store David Bowie in your database then) or with two different heights, which you probably don't want. You would have to trust your programs and yourself to be careful about this, because the dbms would no longer help you regarding this.
2. Use new tables for this.

However, as there are three types of attributes then (single fixed, multiple fixed, single variable) we could introduce this as a main key in your database (primary keys bold):

- attribute_type (**att_type**, description) -> SINGLE_FIXED, MULTI_FIXED, SINGLE_VAR
- attibute (**att_type, att_no**, description) -> EYES=SINGLE_FIXED, HEIGHT=SINGLE_VAR, NATIONALITY=MULTI_FIXED...
- attribute_value (**att_type, att_no, value**, description) -> Eyes=SINGLE_FIXED=hazel ...
- person_has_attribute_value (**person_id, att_type, att_no, value**) -> Person1=Eyes=SINGLE_FIXED=hazel, Person1=Nationality=MULTI_FIXED=British, Person1=NATIONALITY=MULTI_FIXED=German, ...

Depending on the dbms you could now check conditionally for uniqueness.

In PostgreSQL for example:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_unique_for_single_types ON person_has_attribute_value (person_id, att_type, att_no)
  WHERE att_type IN ('SINGLE_FIXED','SINGLE_VAR');
```

Note, not all dbms offer a way to check for conditional uniqueness. In some you may need computed columns or triggers or function indexes, in others such options may not be available. I must admit, I don't know if it is possible in MySQL.

So it depends on the dbms if this different data model helps. Maybe you should keep it simple and just stick to what you have, add the attribute type to **attribute** for determining the input method and drop the unique constraint.